# How do I find text between two words and export it to txt.file

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file which contains many lines and I want to take the text between `<STR_0.005_Long>,` and `µm,5.000µm`.

Example line from the CSV:

```
Straightness(Up/Down) <STR_0.005_Long>,4.444µm,5.000µm,,Pass,‌​2.476µm,1.968µm,25,0‌​.566µm,0.720µm
```

This is the script that I am trying to write:

```
$arr = @()
$path = "C:\Users\georgi\Desktop\5\test.csv"
$pattern = "(?<=.*<STR_0.005_Long>,)\w+?(?=µm,5.000µm*)"
$Text = Get-Content $path
$Text.GetType() | Format-Table -AutoSize

$Text[14] | Foreach {
    if ([Regex]::IsMatch($_, $pattern)) {
        $arr += [Regex]::Match($_, $pattern)
        Out-File C:\Users\georgi\Desktop\5\test.txt -Append
    }
}
$arr | Foreach {$_.Value} | Out-File C:\Users\georgi\Desktop\5\test.txt -Append
```

Comment: Update your question with sample data instead of a link. (I can't access the link you posted and wouldn't risk downloading it anyway.)

Comment: Straightness(Up/Down)<STR_0.005_Long>,4.444µm,5.000µm,,Pass,2.476µm,1.968µm,25,0.566µm,0.720µm
this is the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Where-Object` filter with your regular expression and simply output the match to the output file:

```
Get-Content $path |
    Where-Object { $_ -match $pattern } |
    ForEach-Object { $matches[0] } |
    Out-File 'C:\Users\georgi\Desktop\5\test.txt'
```

Of course, since you have a CSV, you could simply use `Import-Csv` and export the value of that particular column:

```
Import-Csv $path | Select-Object -Expand 'column_name' |
    Out-File 'C:\Users\georgi\Desktop\5\test.txt'
```

Replace `column_name` with the actual name of the column. If the CSV doesn't have a column header you can specify one via the `-Header` parameter:

```
Import-Csv $path -Header 'col1','col2','col3',... |
    Select-Object -Expand 'col2' |
    Out-File 'C:\Users\georgi\Desktop\5\test.txt'
```

Comment: When I use 
    Import-Csv $path -Header 'col1','col2','col3',... |
    Select-Object -Expand 'col2' |
    Out-File 'C:\Users\georgi\Desktop\5\test.txt'
In the Out file I have meny characteristics. I want to have only 4.444

Comment: Put a filter after the import: `... | Where-Object { $_.col2 -eq '4.444' } | ...`

Comment: I did it with the following script :
    $path = "C:\Users\georgi\Desktop\5\test.csv"
$X = Get-Content $path  | Select -Index 14
$A = $X.Substring(43,5) 
$B = $B = "000" + $A +"0" | Set-Content -Path ('C:\Users\georgi\Desktop\5\test.txt')